# Is it possible to get an adjustable "view" of a static image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I'm working on a web app where I have an image, and, for lack of a better word, a "view" of that image which is a box limiting what you can see to whatever part of the image is inside the box.  The view can be adjusted by dragging the edges around, and the image is stays.  However, I also want to be able to drag both the view and the image around together.

The best analogy I can think of is the Snipping Tool in Windows that you use to capture a portion of your screen.

I've tried a div with a background image, but that always resizes the image to fit the div.  Right now I'm trying to have a div that contains an img, and setting the div to have overflow:hidden, but that makes the image stick to the upper left corner of the div.

Help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at JCrop? http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Comment: Now I have.  Seemed promising at first, but I think it's too specific to be used in this case.  The image and view need to be a set height, with the sides adjustable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something that masks the image and only shows a segment.

Assuming a structure like.

```
<div class="img-mask">
    <img>
</div>
```

You can set the styles of the mask to be overflow hidden with a width and a height (this creates the mask). Then position the image relatively, left and top till it's where you want it to be.

```
.img-mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.img-mask img {
    position: relative;
    top: -25%;
    left: -25%;
}
```

This should center the image to the mask.

Comment: I believe resizing the mask from the left would still shift the underlying image around, right? I think the two elements need to be on a parallel level in the DOM somehow, but I'm lost there...

Comment: If you apply the left and top positions as percentages, yes, that is true. However, if they are set using px, the are relative to the top left hand corner. So if you increace/decreace the width/height of the mask, the image won't move as all you're changing is the bottom right hand corner of the mask.

Comment: If you want to be really tricky about it. You could create another div wrapping the mask which also has a copy of the image (set to a low opacity). Position the mask and it's child image absolutely to the wrapping div (set left and top to 0), then move the mask around using the left and top.

Comment: Well I just got back from the final demo of my project, but my group is enthusiastic enough about it to possibly continue working on it.  I'll try it out when I come back to it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a CSS property cut out for exactly this task: the **clip** attribute.

Here's the W3schools tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp. Click the *Try it Yourself* button to get a hands-on idea.

With this the CSS property applies only on the image and you do not need an additional masking div.